# preventing from re-navigating after pop, in onObserve?

Tags: android, mvvm, navigation, observable, android-livedata

I'm using MVVM + Retrofit + navigation in my new project and calling retrofit from the repository. Now when I receive a response in fragment-A with liveData, I navigate to next fragment-B, everything looks good so far. The problem starts from where in fragment-B I want to pop to the previous fragment and edit something.

In previous fragment(fragment-A) as soon as init, onObserve is called and navigates to fragment-B again!

some solutions came to my mind that worked, like:

1. setValue(null) after navigate to fragment-B
2. Remove observe in onCreateView and observe it when call retrofit from repository(This solution creates other problems)
   and Etc.

```
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // fetch data from server
        viewModel.articles.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {

            //if it was success
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.fragment_a_to_fragment_b)


            }
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to use something like following https://proandroiddev.com/livedata-with-single-events-2395dea972a8 (or generally search for `SingleLiveEvent`)

Comment: tnx king. you are the one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In scenarios where payload of a live data should be handled only once, you should use an event class which wraps the payload:

```
open class Event<out T>(private val content: T) {

    var hasBeenHandled = false
        private set // Allow external read but not write

    /**
     * Returns the content and prevents its use again.
     */
    fun getContentIfNotHandled(): T? {
        return if (hasBeenHandled) {
            null
        } else {
            hasBeenHandled = true
            content
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the content, even if it's already been handled.
     */
    fun peekContent(): T = content
}
```

In your view model you should set the event like this:

```
fun loadArticles() {
       val data = // load data from repository
       articles.value = Event(data)  // Trigger the event by setting a new Event as a new value
}
```

Then observe like this:

```
viewModel.articles.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    it.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let { // Only proceed if the event has never been handled
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.fragment_a_to_fragment_b)
    }
})
```

For more info see [LiveData with SnackBar, Navigation and other events (the SingleLiveEvent case)](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150)